# PostgreSQL 11: coalesce() on row_to_json() still returns null

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 11, I’d like to return a row in JSON format. But unfortunately, `COALESCE(row_to_json(t), '{}'::json)` still returns `null`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.get_log(log_id int) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    result text;
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(row_to_json(t), '{}'::json)
    INTO result
    FROM (SELECT id, foo, bar FROM myschema.mytable WHERE id = log_id) t;
    RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I return an empty JSON object if there is no row?

Comment: For the `result` variable to be empty, the inner query you are running likely returned no results. You cannot `COALESCE` across zero rows. What you can probably do, however, is change your return statement to `RETURN COALESCE(result, '{}'::json)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the query returns no results, not that the result is `NULL`.  One method is to aggregate the results -- because you can aggregate json -- and take the first value:

```
SELECT COALESCE( (array_agg(row_to_json(t)))[1], '{}'::json)
INTO result
FROM (SELECT id, foo, bar FROM myschema.mytable WHERE id = log_id) t;

RETURN result;
```

Alternatively, you could you conditional logic:

```
if not exists () then use '{}'::json
else use your query
```